# Not all Toasts called successively (one after another) appearing on screen (Xamarin.Android)

Tags: xamarin.android, toast

I have the following method:

```
public void ImportXMLFileIntoDatabase<T, U>(string xmlFileLocation, string xmlFileName, string databaseFolderPath, string objectsToImport)
        where U : IPlural<T> where T : new()
{
    string xmlFileFullPath = xmlFileLocation + "/" + xmlFileName;
    XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(U));
    TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(xmlFileFullPath);
    U u = (U)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
    textReader.Close();
    //Import into database
    var connection = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(databaseFolderPath, "MobileSell.db")))
    connection.DeleteAll<T>();
    List<T> all = u.All;
    connection.InsertAll(all);
    int numElementsImported = connection.Table<T>().ToList().Count;
    Toast.MakeText(this, "Imported " + numElementsImported + " " + objectsToImport, ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
```

That method deserializes `XML` file into `C#` objects and inserts the object into database (before doing that, it deletes all records from database).

I call that method 6 times:

```
ImportXMLFileIntoDatabase<Article, Articles>(pathFromserverFolder, "articles.xml", apkFolder, "артикули");
ImportXMLFileIntoDatabase<Customer, Customers>(pathFromserverFolder, "customers.xml", apkFolder, "клиенти");
ImportXMLFileIntoDatabase<Sertif, Sertifs>(pathFromserverFolder, "sertif.xml", apkFolder, "сертификати");
ImportXMLFileIntoDatabase<CustDiscount, CustDiscounts>(pathFromserverFolder, "custdisc.xml", apkFolder, "отстъпки");
ImportXMLFileIntoDatabase<Group, Groups>(pathFromserverFolder, "groups.xml", apkFolder, "групи");
ImportXMLFileIntoDatabase<Route, Routes>(pathFromserverFolder, "routes.xml", apkFolder, "маршрути");
```

But I only recieve the `Toast` message for the last 3 calls and they appear and dissappear too fast. How can I make the first 3 toasts appear too? It seems to me also that all 3 Toasts messages appear after all inserts to all tables have occured. And I want the Toast to appear after every insert and to stay on screen `ToastLenght.Short time`.

Comment: Could you please set break points to debug your codes and check whether your datas are inserted into database correctly?

Comment: The data is inserted correctly. I cheked

Comment: And `Toast.MakeText` for the first 3 calls get executed correctly? Then it makes no sense that you won't receive the message for first 3 calls.